# Controller action HttpGet executes wrong action

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a new Web API project from the Visual Studio Templates and then I have followed the following tutorial for adding OData to this project.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/supercharging-asp-net-core-api-with-odata/

Calling
**https://localhost:xxx/api/Assets**
and 
**https://localhost:xxx/api/Assets/1**

return all Assets, while the latter should return only 1 asset (where id = 1)

My code:

```
public class AssetsController : ControllerBase
{
    private IAssetService _service;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public AssetsController (IAssetService _service, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this._service = _service;
        this._mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Asset>> Get()
    {
        return this._service.GetAllAssets().ToList();
    }


    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [EnableQuery()]
    public Asset Get(int id)
    {
        return _service.GetById(id);
    }
}
```

I have debugged to verify that the `Get(int id)` function is never called.

I have tried defining my route explicitly like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetById/{id}")]
[EnableQuery()]
public Asset Get(int id)
{
    return _service.GetById(id);
}
```

**EDIT**

Routing defined in startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            /* snip */

            app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
            {
                routeBuilder.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routeBuilder.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().MaxTop(10);
                routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("api", "api", GetEdmModel());
            });

        }
```

This makes no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any routing defined in startup too?

Comment: Edited my code to include my default route!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two approaches to solve this question.

**Approach 1 : rename the `id` parameter to `key`**

According to the [OData v4 Web API docs](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions) :

> *Here are some rules for the method signatures:*
>
> - ***If the path contains a key, the action should have a parameter named key.***
> - *If the path contains a key into a navigation property, the action should have a > parameter named relatedKey.*
> - *POST and PUT requests take a parameter of the entity type.*
> - *PATCH requests take a parameter of type Delta, where T is the entity type.*

We should have a parameter named `key`:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]  // actually, this line doesn't matter if you're using OData, but it's better to rename it to `key` too
[EnableQuery()]
public IActionResult Get(int key)
{
    ....
}
```

---

**Approach 2: rename the `Get` method to `GetAsset`**

According to [OData v4 Web API docs](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions):

> *When Web API gets an OData request, **it maps the request to a controller name and an action name**. The mapping is based on the HTTP method and the URI. For example, GET /odata/Products(1) maps to ProductsController.GetProduct.*

We could also rename the action method to `GetAsset` as below:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[EnableQuery()]
public IActionResult GetAsset(int id)
{
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. You answered my question and solved it. +1 also for linking to the OData docs. I've been reading up on the Web API docs and didn't realize that the routing was different due to OData.

Answer (score 0):

this worked me...

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Asset>> Get()
{
    return this._service.GetAllAssets().ToList();
}


[HttpGet("{id}")]
public Asset Get(int id)
{
    return _service.GetById(id);
}
```

Comment: I also suspect OData has something to do with this, but I have no idea where to begin to be honest